# Obtener grupo de metodos de una clase solo con el nombre

Tags: c#

tengo mi clase

```
class MyClass
{
  public string MyString{ get; set; }
}
```

y tengo un metodo a parte que usa la clase MyClass

```
myMethod<MyClass>();
```

necesito obtener `MyClass` solo colocando el nombre para ser usado en el método

estoy usando

```
Type tipotabla = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyCLass");
```

pero obtengo el tipo y no puede ser usado en el método

`myMethod` es un método que yo conozco y puedo invocar, lo que es variable es 
`MyClass`, de los cuales tengo varias clases con distintos nombres, por eso necesito que solo con el nombre de la clase pueda obtener el grupo de métodos para ser usado

Estoy usando Dapper para obtener información de base de datos y el nombre de la clase es el nombre de la tabla y cada uno de los campos de la tabla son los campos de la clase y con dapper enviando la clase, creara una lista de ese tipo con la información y no una variable dinámica.

la forma en que lo hago dinamicamente es la siguiente

```
 public object SelectAll<T>()
    {
        ///Obtiene el select de la tabla con todos los campos del objeto
        try
        {
            string campos = string.Empty;
            foreach (var campo in typeof(T).GetProperties())
            {
                campos = campos + campo.Name + ", ";
            }
            campos = campos.Remove(campos.Length - 2);
            string consulta = string.Format("SELECT {0} FROM {1}", campos, typeof(T).Name);

            using (var connection = GetConnectionCr6())
            {
                var res = connection.Query<T>(consulta).ToList();
                return res;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
```

y obtengo la info asi

```
(T)query = SelectAll<T>();
```

Comment: A ver si te he entendido..lo que quieres es llamar a un método usando una cadena con su nombre? O lo que quieres es poder usar `tipotabla` como tipo de `myMethod` asi -> `myMethod<tipotabla>`?

Comment: si exactamente @Pikoh tipotabla tendra una de las tantas clases que tengo para ser usada en el metodo

Comment: Si tu metodo va a devolver algo que no sabes que es, para que pasarle el nombre... no deberias pasarle una clase padre de todas esas. Porque si no sabes que nombre vas a usar, definitivamente no vas a saber que contiene.. todos deberian heredar del mismo.. Tal vez podrias describir un poco mas porque queres hacer esto...

Comment: el metodo devolvera un elemento del tipo MyClass, en este caso del tipo tipotabla, por eso debo enviarselo para hacer el cast dentro del metodo

Comment: LAs propiedades de una tabla son siempre las mismas... Ahi me confundiste.. Tendrias una clase tabla, que para cualquier tabla tiene siempre las mismas propiedas.. o de que propiedades hablas?

Comment: Disculpa no era propiedad era campo

Comment: Hasta donde tengo entendido Dapper ya te devuelve una lista del tipo de clase que le especifiques y no necesariamente dinamica.

Comment: Vale, te había entendido al revés. Creo que mi respuesta es lo que buscas.

Comment: exacto @OrlandoDeLaRosa Dapper devuelve una lista del tipo de clase que le especifiques y eso es lo que deseo obtener el tipo de clase solo teniendo el nombre de la clase como string

Comment: Pero si vas a hacer una queyr con dapper.. ya sabes que query es.. Salvo que estes pasando una query que este en otro lado.. podrias mostrar el escenario completo de tu idea?

Comment: Como dice @gbianchi si ya sabes el query, entonces debes de saber el tipo de clase?

Comment: Creo que esto esta mas cerca de ser lo que llamamos un [problema XY](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3360/324)

Comment: Segun tu codigo y lo que comentas el metodo `myMethod` es generico, ese metodo que te debe de retornar?. Por que ya `myMethod` debe de estar declarado de esta forma `myMethod<T>` y dentro de el al hacer la consulta con Dapper solo le vuelves a pasar T cuando haces el `Query<T>`. Lo mejor es que coloques el codigo del metodo.

Comment: el query siempre sera distinto, por que el nombre de la clase es el nombre de la tabla y cada uno de los campos dinamicamente los envio en el select para no hacer un select *

Comment: Vamos a ver.. tenes un metodo que va a devolver algo que no sabes que es, y le vas a pasar el nombre de una clase, eso va a hacer un query que de alguna forma se va a armar magicamente para pegarle a la tabla que corresponde, y despues ese metodo te va a devolver que cosa? un T? o un dinamyc? O sea, que vas a hacer a la vuelta con algo que no sabes que es, porque aunque lo definas como var, vas a trabajar todo tu programa por reflection?

Comment: Tu `SelectAll` deberia quedar `public List<T> SelectAll<T>()` de esta forma te ahorras los cast de un objeto a otro tipo.

Comment: Gracias eso me ayuda mucho para el select, pero todavia tengo el problema de obtener T con el nombre de la clase

Comment: Sigo sin enteder porque, y como vas a hacer que tu programa haga algo despues con algo que no sabe que es.. pero bueno... Tene en cuenta que como esta tu modelo, cualquier cambio en la db debe llevar exactamente el mismo cambio en el programa. Y viceversa. Y que tus clases no pueden tener mas variables publicas que las que estas usando, o serian agregadas al query.

Comment: es para una migracion los campos no cambiaran pero si es posible siempre obtener la informacion de distintas tablas y la idea no es crear tantos querys como tablas existan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, debes hacer uso de `Reflection` para obtener el [`MethodInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2) de tu método genérico. Posteriormente, para crear la instancia debes usar el método [`MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Reflection_MethodInfo_MakeGenericMethod_System_Type___) con el tipo, y por último, invocarlo. Asi:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(clase).GetMethod("myMethod");
Type tipo = Type.GetType("MyProject.MyCLass");
MethodInfo generico = method.MakeGenericMethod(tipo);
clase c = new clase();
generico.Invoke(c,null);
```

Comment: pero para ti clase que seria? teniendo en cuenta que myMethod si lo conozco y siempre sera el mismo la variable es MyProject.MyCLass

Comment: @CarlosMario `clase` es la clase donde está tu método `myMethod`. Esté además debería ser público (si no, hay que hacer una modificación a este código)

Comment: estoy obteniendo este error "El objeto no coincide con el tipo de destino."

Comment: si tiene parameros pero se los quite solo por hacer la prueba, no tiene restriccion de tipo, pero igual ya ingresare el codigo

Comment: @CarlosMario `myMethod` está en una clase distinta a desde donde lo ejecutas?

Comment: si pero al hacer MethodInfo method = typeof(clase).GetMethod("myMethod"); si esta obteniendo bien la informacion, exactamente esta en la clase Querys

Comment: @CarlosMario el error te da en el invoke?

Comment: si exactamente.

Comment: @CarlosMario vale, al estar en otra clase, debes instanciarla para realmente poder llamar al metodo con `Invoke`. Mira mi respuesta ahora. (Si la clase o el método son estáticos, es posible que haya que modificar esto)

Comment: Muchisimas gracias @Pikoh tu respuesta es correcta ya obtengo T perfectamente.. nuevamente muchas gracias